# How to change options on Android GoogleMap from Java?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm trying to add options to my xml-defined google map in my (first!) Android App. From Java I now want to change some options. I try to do this as follows:

GoogleMap mMap = null;

```
if (mMap == null) {
    mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    if (mMap != null) { 
        Log.wtf("DE MAP IS", "GECREEERD!!!");
        GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions();
        options.mapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE)
                .compassEnabled(false)
                .rotateGesturesEnabled(false)
                .tiltGesturesEnabled(false);
        mMap.newInstance(options);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I get an error at `mMap.newInstance(options);` saying "*The method newInstance(GoogleMapOptions) is undefined for the type GoogleMap*".

Does anybody know how I can fix this? All tips are welcome!

Comment: Very late... but still relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22068451/setting-googlemapoptions-programatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this to select options

```
int mapType =  GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE;

FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
map = mapFragment.getMap();
map.setMapType(mapType);
```