# Setting GoogleMapOptions programmatically

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am inflating my fragment like this:

```
GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.MapFragment_map_Fragment)).getMap();
```

and here I have my options:

```
GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions();
options.mapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
```

In the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#programmatically) I see that I need to use this:

> To apply these options when you are creating a map, do one of the
>   following:
>
> If you are using a MapFragment, use the
>   MapFragment.newInstance(GoogleMapOptions options) static factory
>   method to construct the fragment and pass in your custom configured
>   options.

But I don't understand how am I suppose to use this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you can use `GoogleMapOptions` only if you are creating map view programmatically(passing options to `MapFragment.newInstance()` method - [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMapOptions.html)). You are inflating `MapFragment` from xml so you wont be able to use them in that way. In your case you can still change map options by using `GoogleMap` setters or `UiSettings`.

For example:

```
GoogleMap googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment)).getMap();
googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 5):

I use LiteMode programmatically instead of setting attribute of MapView and MapFragment in XML file. Try this:

```
GoogleMapOptions googleMapOptions = new GoogleMapOptions().liteMode(true);
googleMap.setMapType(googleMapOptions.getMapType());
```

Or in XML:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.mapslastapp.MapsActivity"
    map:liteMode="true"
    map:cameraZoom="16"
    map:mapType="normal"/>
```